# Downloaded Media from firebase storage does'not appear in gallery but appears in file explorer

Tags: android

```
final File localFile = new File(Gett.getVideoDir(), helper.getCloud_name() + "." + helper.getExt());

                StorageReference reference = Reff.getChatVideoReference().child(helper.getCloud_name());
                holder.iPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.uploadProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                reference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // Local temp file has been
                        Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: Downloaded");

                    }
                });
```

I google it and found i need to add metadata to file. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I might be late but it may help others.

We need to add metadata to our downloaded files.
for this use this code in onSuccess()

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
                        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, helper.getCloud_name()+"."+helper.getExt());
                        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        itemView.getContext().getContentResolver().insert
                                (MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```